# Applying multiple css classes in angular

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to apply multiple classes `.active` on item click and another class based on some condition. How can i do both? Below is the code which I have and only `MyAnotherClass` gets applied.

```
<li ng-class="(item.name == currentState && 'active' && isItemValid(item) && 'myAnotherClass' )" ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
        <a ui-sref="{{item.name}}"  ng-click="selectedItem(item)">{{item.name}}</a> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ng-class`, you can separate the classes (and their respective rules (expressions)) using a comma separated listing.

Here is an example:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': isActive && !isDeleted, 'myAnotherClass': isValidOtherClass}"></li>
```

This technique should allow you to accomplish any combination of dynamically applied classes.

[Documentation for ng-class is here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass).

Answer (score 1):

Per the [ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) directive documentation, use an object literal with keys of the class names to apply and values of the boolean variables to indicate to add/remove the classes.

It appears that you can use expressions that resolve to booleans in place of a variable in v1.2.6. However, I haven't tested functions.

```
<li ng-class="{ active: item.name == currentClickState, myAnotherClass: isItemValid(item) }" ng-repeat="item in navigationMenuItems">
    <a ui-sref="{{item.name}}"  ng-click="selectedItem(item)">{{item.name}}</a> 
</li>
```

P.S. Have a look at [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). With `&&` the `myAnotherClass` is only applied if every statements before it is truthy, and `active` will never be applied as that string is truthy and the next statement is tested. I'm guessing you were intending something like `(item.name===currentClickState ? 'active' :'')+(isItemValid(item) ? 'myAnotherClass' :'')` (That's a [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator))